# Angular: Add a click Method to a tag - property binding in strings

Tags: angular

I want to add a click Method in this code and a variable in the a tag. Can someone show me how this works?
After that the string is to be inserted into an innerHTML.

```
let ab:string = '<span id=$start class="grammar__warning"> <a (click)="addListenerToSpan('$event')"> "$variable"</a> </span>'
```

Edit:
I render that like this:

```
 <div class="menu" id="menu" [innerHTML]="htmlText"></div>
```

I replace a part of text (the text in the id=menu) with a span, to have some css style and a clickable button there.

```
this.htmlText = this.htmlText.replace(this.htmlText.substr(start-1, end - start), ab);
```

Comment: how are you rendering this ?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: where is the  variable ab in 
<div class="menu" id="menu" [innerHTML]="htmlText"></div>

Comment: I hope this can help you

Comment: this isn't really how the angular framework works. you should take a step back and try to explain what problem you're trying to solve so people can provide alternative solutions that work within the framework better, rather than asking how to make this particular solution work

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will work:

```
<div class="menu" id="menu" style="cursor: pointer;" [innerHTML]="htmlText"></div>
```

or just in css:

```
.menu{ cursor: pointer;}
```

Comment: I need the div in a string with a onClick method